# SQL Server MERGE with Insert subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, merge, subquery

I'm having trouble getting this compound insert to work in my MERGE statement between two tables (Ignore the when match condition, I know its bad practice). The issue I'm having is getting the ServerId field in the target table to fill. The Team field is filling fine but all of the rows have a null value for ServerId. I can't find an example online for this so I'm hoping someone can help. I don't seem to have any syntactical errors and I know the column 'ServerName' in the Source table is filled for all rows.

```
    MERGE ApplicationTeams AS Target
    USING TempApplicationTeams AS Source
    ON (Target.ServerId = (SELECT ID from Servers WHERE Name='Source.ServerName') AND Target.Team = Source.Team)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET Target.Team = Target.Team
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (ServerId, Team) VALUES((SELECT ID from Servers WHERE Name='Source.ServerName'), Source.Team)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
    DELETE
    ;
```

Thanks.

Comment: why wouldn't you use the subquery as part of your source?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should remove the single quoutes on the *where* clausule.

You wrote:
 **(SELECT ID from Servers WHERE Name='Source.ServerName')**

But I think you should write this:
 **(SELECT ID from Servers WHERE Name=Source.ServerName)**

And make sure the *select id* returns only one row otherwise the statement will fail

I hope it will be usefully

Comment: Thank you so much! Thought I had read somewhere else that maybe subqueries weren't allowed in SQL Merge statements. You saved my day, man.